# How to Change Color of Div within a for statement?

Tags: javascript

Inside my php while loop I output a div with id divborder, and class div-border
 Inside that div i have another div with id title

```
<div id='divborder' class='div-border'>
  <div id='Title'>This is Title</div> <br/> video elements
</div>
```

I have a JavaScript function that get called when the video ends

```
for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
  videos[i].addEventListener("ended", function(event) 
  {
     var divBoader2 = document.getElementsByClassName("divborder")[3];
     divBoader2.style.borderColor = "#b1ff99";
  }
```

My Question is how do i change the border color of the div and the title of second div?

I can do it like this:

```
var divBoader2 = document.getElementsByClassName("divborder")[3];
divBoader2.style.borderColor = "#b1ff99";
```

which works but its not dynamic

Comment: Please post entire code from your javascript function.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("divborder")[3]` why 3? what is the significance of 3 here? What dynamism do you want?

Comment: @gurvinder372 that was me trying to make it work, ideally i  want to change the color and text of the currently ended video so [3] works but if a different video plays it changes the color of [3] I tried to put [i] but that does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the value of value at `i` in another variable declared with `let`

```
for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
  let index = i; //save the value as let so that its binding stays
  videos[i].addEventListener("ended", function(event) 
  {
     var divBoader = document.querySelectorAll("div-border")[index];
     divBoader.style.borderColor = "#b1ff99";
  }
}
```

Or if the video elements are within the `div-border`, then use [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

```
for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
  videos[i].addEventListener("ended", function(event) 
  {
     var divBoader = event.currentTarget.closest(".div-border");
     divBoader.style.borderColor = "#b1ff99";
  }
}
```

A little less verbose code

```
[...videos].forEach( s => s.closest( ".div-border" ).style.color = "#b1ff99" )
```

Comment: This worked Perfectly Thanks. I've accepted the answer you save me a lot of time Thank YOU!!

Comment: Sure, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Give class name `div-border` instead of `divborder`

```
for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
 videos[i].addEventListener("ended", function(event) 
 {
    var divBoader2 = document.getElementsByClassName("div-border")[3];
    divBoader2.style.borderColor = "#b1ff99";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is probably a `videos[i].parentNode` instead of `document.getElementsByClassName("div-border")[3]` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode)